Constructing compatible functions $\phi'_i,\phi'_j$ for equivalence relation $\sim$ for directed limit of directed systems of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz, and How to Prove it by: Dan Velleman.
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then, the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2: The direct sum of the family of the subgroup is defined as
$$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i=\{f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i\}$$
with the restricted operation.
Definition 3:  Suppose $R$ is an equivalence-relation on a set $A,$ and $x\in A.$  Then the *equivlanece class of x with respect to * $R$ is the set
$$[x]_R=\{y\in A\mid yRx\}\quad\quad (*)$$
If $R$ is clear from context, then we just write $[x]$ instead of $[x]_R.$  The set of all equivalence classes of elements of $A$ is called $A$ modulo $R,$ and is denoted $A/R$.
$$A/R=\{[x]_R\mid x\in A\}=\{X\subset A\mid \exists x\in A(X=[x]_R)\}\quad\quad (**)$$
Definition 4:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 5: Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, We will say that $f$ is compatible with $R$ if $\forall x\in A\forall y\in A(xRy\to f(x)=f(y))$.
Definition 6:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 7:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,

[Note:  the correct partial order should be:  $i\preceq j$.]

if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

[Note:  the correct compositional map should be:  $\phi^{'}_i=\phi\circ \phi_i$.]
The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their images in $G_k$.
Questions:
This is a continuation from this post.  If I want to talk about for Definition 7 (in the context of Definition 5) how a function $f$ is compatible with an equivalence relation $\sim$.
In order to construct the Definition 5, can I do the following:
from Definition 7 $1.$, I let $A=G_i, G_j$, $R=\sim$ and $A/R=\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$, and $B=G'$, then
$x_i\sim x_j$ if and only if $\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)\in G_k$, and $\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)=x_k\in G_k$. then from the following two composition maps:
$G_i\xrightarrow{\phi_{ik}}G_k\xrightarrow{\phi_k}\oplus_i G_i/\sim=G_i\xrightarrow{\phi_{i}}\oplus_i G_i/\sim$
$G_j\xrightarrow{\phi_{jk}}G_k\xrightarrow{\phi_k}\oplus_i G_i/\sim=G_j\xrightarrow{\phi_{j}}\oplus_i G_i/\sim$
in $1.$ of Definition 7, we have $\phi_i(x_i)=(\phi_k\circ \phi_{ik})(x_i)=\phi_k(x_k)$, and $\phi_j(x_j)=(\phi_k\circ \phi_{jk})(x_j)=\phi_k(x_k)$.
From the universal mapping property for $2.$ in Definition 7.
$G_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i}\oplus_i G_i/\sim\xrightarrow{\phi}G'=G_i\xrightarrow{\phi^{'}_{i}}G'$
$G_j\xrightarrow{\phi_j}\oplus_i G_i/\sim\xrightarrow{\phi}G'=G_j\xrightarrow{\phi^{'}_{j}}G'$
where both $\phi_i, \phi_j$ are respectively injection maps from $G_i\to \oplus_{i\in I} G_i/\sim$  and $G_j\to \oplus_{j\in I} G_j/\sim$.  So we have:
$\phi'_i(x_i)=(\phi\circ \phi_i)(x_i)=\phi(\phi_k(x_k))=(\phi\circ \phi_j)(x_j)=\phi'_j(x_j)$.
All this gives us $\forall x_i\in G_i\forall x_j\in G_j(x_1\sim x_j\to \phi'_i(x_i)=\phi'_j(x_j))$, where $\phi'_i:G_i\to G', \phi'_j:G_j\to G'$, and both are compatible with the equivalence relation $\sim$, which is Definition 5.
Thank you in advance

I don't get what your question is, definition 5 is a definition, there is nothing to construct? Is your question "why the quotient map $$\bigoplus G_i \to \lim_\to G_i$$ compatible with the relation of equivalence?

@julio_es_sui_glace for Definition 5, what should be the corresponding compatible function $f$ be from Definition 7?  There are a lot of functions and composition maps.

@julio_es_sui_glace how did you get $\bigoplus G_i \to \lim_\to G_i$ as the function that is compatible with the equivalence relation?

I guess I gave out the answer, when you do a quotient $X/R$ you have a map $\pi:X \to X /R$ that sends $x$ on $[x]_R$ its class of equivalence. Here $\mathrm{colim} G_i$ is the quotient of $\bigoplus G_i$ by an equivalence relation, your map is thus the quotient map

@julio_es_sui_glace so the corresponding function in Definition 7 would be the $\phi$ map in $2.$?  The thing is the compatible map is suppose to equal to a composition of maps?  THere is a lot of composition of maps, and hence a lot of commutative diagrams going on. I am having a bit of trouble matching which one is the correct compatible map.  From your answer, it would correspond to the $\phi$ where $\phi:G=\oplus_i G_i/\sim\to G'$.  Or am I missing something?

@julio_es_sui_glace another thing is, if we have $\pi:X\to X/R$, then  according to Definition 7, then $X=\oplus_i G_i, X/R=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$, but don't compatible function of an equivalence relation go from $\oplus_i G_i\to G'$, or is it from $\oplus_i G_i\to \oplus_i G_i/\sim$?

Here $G' = \lim G_i$ (you must prove it is a group)

@julio_es_sui_glace i detleted my previous comment because I relaized I made a mistake.  I think you meant to say that $G=\oplus_i G_i$ and $G'=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$.  So we are talking about a projection function like $\pi:X\to X/R$?
